# What does "legal jumping jacks" mean in the marketing context?

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology, business-language, marketing

I came across the expression "legal jumping jacks" in a sentence from a sales pitch text which is explaining why that company is good to buy a service from.

The sentence is like as below:

> > We(the company) have partners who understand the legal jumping jacks used by commercial vendors.

I consulted the internet but couldn't find a meaning of jumping jack other than the exercise which is obviously not what it means in the above sentence.

Could anybody please help me understand this?

Comment: How does the exercise not fit, metaphorically?

Comment: I think this may be a mixed metaphor conflating *jumping jacks* with *jumping through hoops*. Can you provide the full context?